# Extract JSON data from struct in struct

Tags: json, struct, coldfusion, cfml

See the output of a deserializeJSON(query).

[image]

For each row, how i can extract only id and DTIME? Following is my code:

```
 <cfscript>
  record=deserializeJSON(query_testing.data_test);

  writeDump(record);

</cfscript>
```

Below is a sample data in "query_testing.data_test":

```
 '{"id3":
        {"DECISION":1,
        "DTIME":"2013-10-18 16:17:28"},
   "id5":
        {"DECISION":1,
        "DTIME":"2013-10-09 15:43:35",}
  }'
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `query`.

Comment: i just query a column named "data_test" and the query name is query_testing. field in the column is in json format. sorry if my term is wrong. haha

Comment: Are you on Lucee or Railo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfscript>

    record = deserializeJSON(query_testing.data_test);

    rows = [];
    for (id in record) {

        rows.add({
            id:    reReplace(id, "^id", ""),
            dtime: record[id].DTIME
        });
    }
    writeDump(rows);

</cfscript>
```

---

Here's the tag variant and a usage example as requested:

```
<cfset record = deserializeJSON(query_testing.data_test)>

<cfset rows = []>
<cfloop collection="#record#" item="id">

    <cfset rows.add({
        id:    reReplace(id, "^id", ""),
        dtime: record[id].DTIME
    })>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#rows#">

<!--- print as table --->
<cfoutput>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>dtime</th>
        </tr>
        <cfloop array="#rows#" index="row">
            <tr>
                <td>#encodeForHtml(row.id)#</td>
                <td>#dateTimeFormat(row.dtime, "yyyy-mm-dd, HH:nn:ss")#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: how to do this in _<cfoutput>_ instead _<cfscript>_

Comment: @uuniniCORN I added the tag variant and a usage example to my answer.